# Swift Master-Detail Template App Mystery

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet, option-type

I'm getting a `Can't unwrap Optional.None` error when running a slightly modified version of the Master-Detail App in Swift.

All I did was add a second `UILabel` to the **DetailViewController**, right under the pre-existing `detailDescriptionLabel`, and when I navigate to the **DetailViewController** from the **MasterViewController** I crash on the statement which sets my new Label:

```
        secondLabel.text = "This is the Second Label"
```

I declare this label is as followed:

```
@IBOutlet var secondLabel : UILabel
```

What's really interesting is that the pre-existing code for setting the `detailDescriptionLabel` includes the new optional `let` syntax:

```
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text = "This is the Detail View"
        }
```

So why is it that we need a `let` statement here for `detailDescriptionLabel`? It was never declared as an Optional Label, it was declared like any regular Label IBOutlet property, like so:

```
@IBOutlet var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel
```

so why is it being treated as an Optional?

And does this mean that from now on any object I add as an IBOutlet will also have to go through this sort of `let` statement if I want to set it through code?

**EDIT:**

I'm crashing in the following method, on the line `anotherLabel.text = "Second Label"`:

```
func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let theCar: CarObject = self.detailItem as? CarObject {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text = theCar.make
        }
        anotherLabel.text = "Second Label"
    }
}
```

but when I treat `anotherLabel` with the whole `if let` business, as follows, it works perfectly well:

```
if let label2 = self.anotherLabel {
    label2.text = "Second Label"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties declared with `@IBOutlet` are always implicitly unwrapped optional variables. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-XID_58) explains it this way:

> When you declare an outlet in Swift, the compiler automatically
>   converts the type to a weak implicitly unwrapped optional and assigns
>   it an initial value of nil. In effect, the compiler replaces 
>   `@IBOutlet var name: Type` with `@IBOutlet weak var name: Type! = nil`.
>    The compiler
>   converts the type to an implicitly unwrapped optional so that you
>   aren’t required to assign a value in an initializer. It is implicitly
>   unwrapped because after your class is initialized from a storyboard or
>   xib file, you can assume that the outlet has been connected. Outlets
>   are weak by default because the outlets you create usually have weak
>   relationships.

Since it's implicitly unwrapped, you don't **have** to go through `if let label = something` every time, just know that if your label is `nil` and you try to work with it, you'll end up with a runtime error. I'm guessing your second label isn't hooked up in Interface Builder -- is that the case? [OP: Nope!]

---

Okay, what's happening in this specific case is that the `configureView()` method can get called from the master view controller's `prepareForSegue()`, since the `detailItem` property on the detail view controller has a `didSet` handler. When that happens, the detail view controller hasn't been loaded yet, so no labels have been created. Since the labels will get set up at the same time, you could put both initializations under that one if statement (and make it a bit more clear, even):

```
func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let theCar: CarObject = self.detailItem as? CarObject {
        if self.detailDescriptionLabel != nil {
            self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = theCar.make
            self.secondLabel.text = "Second Label"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my second Label is _absolutely_ hooked up in Interface Builder! :-) I dragged-n-dropped from it right into the code, as per usual, so its definitely hooked up. (I also double-checked with the Connections Inspector.) So how do I _not_ go through the `if let label = something` if I want to assign text to my Label?

Comment: Can you post a little more code? What method are you crashing in? (You can throw the whole thing up at gist.github.com if that's easier.)

Comment: sure thing - I added the code to my original question - see above.

Comment: A-ha! Nice catch! :-) And makes perfect sense. Much obliged - marking as right answer :-)